# Variable value is not displaying in Jquery Graph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, charts

I am trying to use spark-line graph. I am passing values to graph as a JavaScript variable. But it is not displaying. But I surprised when I give same value as constant/static. It displays Correctly. Here is the my code :-

```
 r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline([1,21,31,12], {
    type: "bar",
    width: "100%",
    height: "30px",
    barWidth: 4,
    barSpacing: 6,
    barColor: "#16D39A"
```

}

This above code working fine but If I take these values in Javascript variable like following code, graph does not work:-

```
var graph_val='1,21,31,12';
r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline([graph_val], {
    type: "bar",
    width: "100%",
    height: "30px",
    barWidth: 4,
    barSpacing: 6,
    barColor: "#16D39A"
});
```

Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: var graph_val='1,21,31,12'; its like a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the string inside an array as a single element, you need to instead generate the array of create one.

Option 1: Split string into array

```
var graph_val='1,21,31,12';
r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline(graph_val.split(','), {
```

Option 2: Write the vals as an array

```
var graph_val=[1,21,31,12];
r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline(graph_val, {
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the variable to be an array. So `var graph_val = [1,21,31,12]` is what you need.

```
var graph_val=[1,21,31,12];
r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline(graph_val, {
    type: "bar",
    width: "100%",
    height: "30px",
    barWidth: 4,
    barSpacing: 6,
    barColor: "#16D39A"
});
```

UPDATE:
In the comments you mentioned the value coming from `$("#id").text()` as `'2,5,3,6,8'`. You can turn the comma delimitered string to an integer array like this:

```
graph_val = $("#id").text().split(',');
for (a in graph_val ) {
    graph_val[a] = parseInt(graph_val[a]);
}

r("#sp-tristate-bar-total-revenue").sparkline(graph_val, {
    type: "bar",
    width: "100%",
    height: "30px",
    barWidth: 4,
    barSpacing: 6,
    barColor: "#16D39A"
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w49mpetp/2/

Comment: @AlivetoDie Our answers are the same.
shivamgour, are you sure that you have copied the answer correctly? Look at https://jsfiddle.net/w49mpetp/ to see the difference. The last two outputs are the same so it should work like that.

Comment: this way it will work but
$("#id").text() = 2,5,3,6,8;
im trying these values to the var graph_val=$("#id").text();

Answer (score 0):

the second piece of code does not initialize an array as the first.

try this:

```
var graph_val=[1,21,31,12];
```